# GCSFuse setting times of 'XX': Permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

Debian Bullseye running GCS Fuse, after a series of updates it now give me the setting times error, for example:

`touch hi`

`touch: setting times of 'hi': Permission denied`

I am really at a loss here. Everything is updated.

Comment: can you refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684724/15774176  Is it helpful?

Comment: Considering a bare `touch` doesn't attempt to modify the date at all, this is a puzzler. But if you are trying to set the date, that's a separate syscall that might be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly validate the folders permissions.

then:

As you can validate in the reference [**Access permissions**](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#access-permissions)

As a security measure, fuse itself restricts file system access to the user who mounted the file system (`cf`. [fuse.txt](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#access-permissions)). For this reason, gcsfuse by default shows all files as owned by the invoking user. Therefore you should invoke gcsfuse as the user that will be using the file system, not as root.

If you know what you are doing, you can override these behaviors with the [allow_other](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a33f32244/Documentation/filesystems/fuse.txt#L100-L105) mount option supported by fuse and with the `--uid` and `--gid` flags supported by gcsfuse. Be careful, this may have security implications!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, seems version changes dictate full instead of R/W on the compute instance storage option.

Comment: I posted the answer. Figured it out. Not sure why my answer shows down voted.

Comment: Coz there is not much information about how do you debug the issue and how isolate this, even when you made the question with not much context and you provide an answer without details… outputs, screenshots and so on.